# "tempdb metadata memory-optimized" configuration option

Tags: sql-server, tempdb, memory-optimized-tables, sql-server-2019

Checking SQL Server 2019 CTP 2.5 (15.0.1500.28) I found this new configuration option and was wandering what is behind it. Couldn't find any information so far and was wondering if you know where to find more about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can [tell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-ver15?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#ctp-25-april-2019) the feature has not been officially announced yet.

There are a couple of resources available on this feature from members of the community:

[Youtube video from Erik Darling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2MgFbEUeu8)

[Blog post from Ned Otter](http://nedotter.com/archive/2018/11/sql-2019-in-memory-hotness/)

This would appear to be the configuration option that will allow you to put some TempDB metadata tables into memory, preventing many types of resource wait and hopefully speeding use of that database up on busy systems. The value of the configuration option can be found with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.configurations
WHERE configuration_id = 1589
```

Answer (score 2):

Uses memory-optimized tables to hold tempdb metadata to eliminate the PAGELATCH_UP and PAGELATCH_EX waits

Answer (score 1):

New in-memory database feature, memory-optimized tempdb metadata added.
See below link
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sqlallproducts-allversions#memory-optimized-tempdb-metadata